# Deleting SharePoint survey results on daily bases

Tags: survey-list, sharepoint-server, survey

I have created a survey where users can indicate which sandwich they want to eat for lunch.
Now I want the results to be deleted on a daily bases. Is this possible? I can't seem to find any options to set a workflow to delete every option at a certain time. I am using SharePoint server 2013.

Thanks !

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a site workflow then this can be scheduled to run at a certain time and can delete the items in your list.

A list based workflow would probably have to pause until a certain time and then delete the items when it wakes up.

Alternatively you could possibly set a policy on the list to delete items older than a certain age?

Comment: Hi Dave

thanks for the comment ! I have tried setting a policy but i get an error : "The list doesn't allow setting of content types " Correlation ID: 2c9c249c-0b7b-7064-5fc0-d4e628c63520

Comment: How come I can't set this policy in the survey settings?

Comment: The survey is a special type of list so I guess it is possible that it does not support content types - however, it seems odd to have the policy option there if you cannot use it.

Comment: I thought so to ... The option is available but when I try to save I allways get the error .

Comment: Hmm - a bit dated but this suggests it is not configurable http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/bd2ab775-395d-49fe-b728-02eb0fddb6ab

Comment: Strange they didn't make the change for the 2013 version. So it's not adjustable but there for the amusement? :P

Comment: I do not have a 2013 immediately handy but just checked in 2010 and have successfully created a policy to delete items when they are 1 day old.  I did this using a list based retention schedule rather than a content type one.  At the top of the page there is an option to change the source - try in 2013?

Comment: I can't seem to find a different source in SP 2013 . When I click the information management policy settings i see some kind of lists with these heading : "Content type" / "Policy" / " Description" / Retention policy defined And there is only 1 item in there the survey i created. I can click it but than i'm redirected on the page that i can't save any changes.

Comment: I think you may be looking in a different place.  Go into the Survey List Settings and click on "Information management policy settings".  By default it is on Content Type Policies but just above that is a section called List Based Retention Schedule with a link saying Change Source - I am looking at this now in a 2013 based O365 site so it is certainly still there in 2013.

Comment: I see the content type policies.But I do not see the list based retntion schedule and the link to change the source.

Comment: Is the O365 version different from the on premise?

Comment: Library and Folder based retention is a site collection level feature that will need to be activated if you want to use this approach.

Comment: where can i activate this feature?

Comment: In site settings - at the site collection level - you will need to be a site collection admin to do this.

Comment: I am site collection admin, i have activated the library and folder based retention. Now when i chagne the source to library and folders will this still apply on my survey? And i don't want any other folders to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think that is not possible OOTB.

Possible options:

- You could create a timerjob to delete the old files
- A scheduled console tool that deletes old entry by a daily basis
- A CSOM script in the survey webpart that deletes old entries
- A endless running workflow
- ...

Comment: could you describe one of these options in detail? I'm kind of new to SharePoint so I don't really know how to handle this.

Comment: Most options are pretty advanced - you need development skills for them. If you want a semi-automatic approach you can utilize the script from here: http://melcher.it/2013/05/powershell-efficiently-empty-large-sharepoint-lists/

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you use SharePoint 2013 workflows, I would suggest:

- To schedule site level SharePoint workflow using [SharePoint Workflow Scheduler](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/)
- Then get all questions using [Get items by query](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/actions-description/#GetItems) custom workflow action from [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/)
- Then iterate through them using loop and delete them one by one.

SharePoint Workflow Scheduler and Workflow Actions Pack are paid tools developed by my team.